# How to get Scale Center data in Apex in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, admin, apex, salesforce-communities, simple-salesforce

In Salesforce there is a feature called [Scale Center](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.scale_center_overview.htm&type=5) which represents Org Performance and Performance Analysis by Reports.
I want to fetch its data in Salesforce Apex, but not able to get any object or anything else by which I get its data in Apex.

Is there any way by which I can get [Scale Center](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.scale_center_overview.htm&type=5) data in Apex?